# Remote MySQL connection works from cmdline, but not with Apache (Webpy, Mod-WSGI)

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, mysql-python, web.py

- Server OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11
- Apache: 2.2.3
- Python: 2.7.6
- Mod_WSGI 4.5.3, Web.Py, MySQLdb

Hey! I have created a Web.Py site that queries data from a remote Oracle database which works perfectly, but I have now run into a problem when trying to create user authentication from a remote MySQL database.

Following the steps from here: http://webpy.org/cookbook/userauthpgsql

The exact same program works from the python commandline, but for some reason when trying to connect to the remote MySQL database from Apache, I get the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> at /login
'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Things I've tried:

1. List item
2. Disabled SELinux
3. Added permissions for apache@myserversIP to the MySQL.
4. Tried both MySQLdb & web.database for the connection
5. Googled a lot.

Here's the code that is being run from my main program:

```
myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host='ip',user='user',passwd='password',db='db',port=3306 );
cHandler = myDB.cursor()
cHandler.execute("SHOW TABLES;")
results = cHandler.fetchall()
for items in results:
print items
```

Any help regarding the issue, or ways to diagnose it further would be appreciated a lot! Thanks

Edit1: I checked where the MySQLdb is being searched from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Which seems to be correct.

Edit2:
    ldd mod_wsgi.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4b5fd000)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: What do you get if you log value of ``MySQLdb.__file__``? Are you sure you don't have a file laying around somewhere in your code called ``MySQLdb.py``?

Comment: Hey Graham! When running through Apache, it's empty and when running from cmdline it's
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.pyc

I'm also sure that I don't have another file with the name MySQLdb.py

Comment: Provide your mod_wsgi configuration? Check what version of Python mod_wsgi is compiled for? Possibly it isn't compiled for your Python 2.7 installation and that is causing all the issues. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: sys.version = '2.7.6 (default, Jun 28 2016, 15:58:57) \n[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)]' sys.prefix = '/usr/local'  
Python version seems to be correct.  
  
This is a dumb question, but I'm unable to find wsgi.conf. It's not in /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf  and locate is unable to find it.

Comment: If you have ``sys.prefix`` of ``/usr/local`` for the Python version you want to use, that can be an immediate problem. Look at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library and work out what ``ldd`` on the ``mod_wsgi.so`` file shows. If it isn't using a Python shared library from ``/usr/local/lib`` that can cause a problem. If you have Python 2.7.X in both system location and ``/usr/local``, you need to build mod_wsgi from source code with special steps so finds correct library.

Comment: I have added ldd results to the original post.
  
I have only one Python 2.7 installed on this server, there is a 2.6 installed as well.

Comment: /lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0  has been linked from: /opt/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0

Comment: If the shared library is from ``/opt/local/lib``, I would not expect ``sys.prefix`` to be ``/usr/local``. Where is the ``python`` binary that yields ``sys.prefix`` of ``/usr/local`` found? How does that relate to what is under ``/opt/local/bin``?

Comment: Okay so I ran sys.executable on both cmd line and on my web app.

Cmdline: /usr/local/bin/python  
Apache: /usr/bin/python ->  Link to /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -> link to  /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: It isn't normal to have Python from ``/usr/local/bin`` linked into ``/usr/bin`` like. You also then have this ``/opt/local`` variant of Python whatever that is. This mess of links with things in different places could well mess up Python initialisation because in an embedded system it uses a strange algorithm to determine where Python is actually installed. You can try setting ``WSGIPythonHome`` to the location of the directory given by ``sys.prefix`` for the proper location of Python, but with the mess of links I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, check to see if there is a file within the same directory as the file you're trying to run, that has the name MySQLdb.py

Comment: I wish it was that easy, but no.